# How would I prove this inequality?

Tags: inequality

$$
\text{ If }x > y > z,\text{ then }xy +yz > \frac{(x + y)(y+z)}{2}
$$
All numbers $x$, $y$ and $z$ are real numbers.

Comment: The question can be re- written as xy+yz > y^2+xz, which further can be written as x(y-z) >y (y-z) i.e x > z i.e equation is bringing us to a result which is true. Hence the inequality is true.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

$$x>y>z\implies (x-y)(y-z)>0$$

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

1. clear denominator
2. then subtract right side from the left side